# Call Delayed Job for an Api Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delay, delayed-job

I have the following controller

```
class V1::LpDeveloperReferralsController < V1::BaseController
 def create
   add(a, b).delay
 end

 def add(a, b)
 end
end
```

I want to be able to call the add method in create method but run it as a delayed job.

At the moment, it doesnt do that.

Comment: where is this `delay` method coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to queue this Api call to make external call or to another endpoint?

You can try below if this helps u..

send_request - > can be your own method to make API call to external

object -> your controller instance

```
class ExampleRequestJob
  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
    Delayed::Job.enqueue self
  end

  def perform
    @response = @object.send_request().with_indifferent_access
  end

  def after(job)
    # want to reattempt if failed
  end

  def error(job, exception)
    #failed
  end

  def success(_job)
    # your success 
  end
end
```